# Extend magento core api get product info with product image url

Tags: android, magento-1.7, ksoap2

How to extend magento core "catalogProductInfo" to get product information along with product's image url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer : get product info along with image URl by the product Ids Call below php method to get required product details, you need to send product Ids in string array.

```
 /**  CUSTOM FILTER API METHOD GET PRODUCT DETAILS WITH IMAGE URL BY PRODUCT_ID's **/
   public function getProductDetails($productidarray){

   $productidstemp = array();
   $productidstemp =   json_decode($productidarray, true);
   $store = 1; $attributes = null; $identifierType = 'ID';

   $result = array();
   $arrlength = count($productidstemp );

   for($x = 0; $x <  $arrlength; $x++) { 

   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productidstemp[$x]);

            $result[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId() ,
            'type'       => $product->getTypeId(),
            'set'        => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
            'sku'        => $product->getSku(),
            'position'   => $product->getCatIndexPosition(),
            'brand'      => $product->getData('brand'),
            'price'      => $product->getData('price'),
            'name'      => $product->getData('name'),
            'description'      => $product->getData('description'),
            'short_description'      => $product->getData('short_description'),
            'image_url'  => $product-> getImageUrl() );

      }

    return  $result; 

   }
```